# What does this thing returns : frame[:, :, ::-1]

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I cant sort out what this section of code is returning    `frame[:, :, ::-1]`

```
success, frame = video_capture.read()
rgb_image = frame[:, :, ::-1]
results = model.detect([rgb_image], verbose=0)
```

Comment: Use `print(rgb_image)` to see what it returns. You should add `opencv` tag as question is related to it.

Answer (score 3):

The first `:` returns all rows, second `:` returns all columns, `::-1` returns the frame channels in a reversed way. [Read more about slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7347631).

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV cv2.VideoCapture.read() returns frame in BGR format so frame[:, :, ::-1] converts it into RGB format.
This is similar to using cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are assigning all rows and all columns in reverse order to **rgb_image** variable.

-1 here significant's that, reverse the list using last index of columns.

It's is also the shortcut way to slice the lists or tuples. In short it's a pythonic way to slice the non linear data structures in Python.